# Sequencing in sql query

Tags: java, sql

How to do sequencing in this type of scenario? how to use order by in this or any other way for sequencing?

QUERY i am using this query:

`select productno,createdt,productcode from matTab order by productno`

output is

```
PO/19-20/106
PO/19-20/110
PO/19-20/101
PO/19-20/114
PO/19-20/150
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/29
```

Intended result is:

```
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/101
PO/19-20/106
PO/19-20/110
PO/19-20/114
PO/19-20/150
PO/19-21/152
PO/19-21/190
PO/19-21/200
```

Comment: What does "sequencing" mean here?  Can you explain that to us?

Comment: actually i want to use above PO numbers in order format in ascending or descending order. so how to do this..

Comment: Tell us which version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), and also give the logic for how to sort using a PO number.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Maybe you could show us what the intended result would be as an example?

Comment: SQL Server is not suitable for handling your requirement.  If you really need to sort this way, you should store each _numerical_ component in a separate column, and then do a multi-column `ORDER BY` in your query.

Comment: Output required in this format:-
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/29
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/81
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/94
PO/19-20/101
PO/19-20/106
PO/19-20/110
PO/19-20/114
PO/19-20/150
PO/19-21/152
PO/19-21/190
PO/19-21/200

Comment: can anyone write query regarding this..

Answer (score 2):

Just add the other 2 Columns to your order by clause, so your Result gets ordered in the way you want.

```
select productno, createdt, productcode 
from matTab 
order by productno, createdt, productcode
```

Hope that helped, Max

Comment: thanks Max. Your suggestion is valuable but i am looking for code through which i get intended result directly, which i looking for

Comment: what is your intended result excactly ? Do you want the whole result in one column? select productno + ' / ' + createdt + ' / ' + productcode

Comment: above mentioned in question which i am looking for, or just get the PO numbers in order format..

Answer (score 0):

If you can store the querying result into a list of POJO, then you can sort the list with customized `Comparator` as follows:

**POJO**
I assume that `createdt` is a string and `productcode` is an integer.

```
class MatTabInfo {
    private String productno;
    private String createdt;
    private int productcode;

    //general getters ans setters
}
```

**Customized comparator**
Compare `createdt`(string) first then `productcode`(integer).

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MatTabInfo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MatTabInfo o1, MatTabInfo o2) {
        if (o1.getCreatedt().compareTo(o2.getCreatedt()) == 0) {
            if (o1.getProductcode() == o2.getProductcode()) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.getProductcode() < o2.getProductcode()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            return o1.getCreatedt().compareTo(o2.getCreatedt());
        }
    }
}
```

**Code snippet**
Sort the list by using `Collections.sort` with customized comparator:

```
List<MatTabInfo> matTabInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
matTabInfoList = ...//generated by querying from DB
Collections.sort(matTabInfoList, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: PO/19-21/152

PO/19-21/190
PO/19-21/200  in this format i am looking and all number should be either in ascending or descending order..

Comment: I wonder know `PO/19-21/152` represents those 3 columns concatenated by '/' or 3 different columns?

Comment: @ashish yadav But your SQL statement selected 3 columns, I cannot figure out why it is based on **only one** column!